# PanacheEntity defaults ID type to Long. How to change this?

Tags: quarkus

PanacheEntity defaults ID type to Long. Distributed database like Spanner prefers UUID. How to override/change the default type?

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need to extends from *PanacheEntity*, you can just as well use [PanacheEntityBase](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.27.0/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntityBase.java#L26) and provide your own ID.

Comment: `PanacheBaseEntity` is now called `PanacheEntityBase` v2.8.2 of Quarkus.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't place a comment, The solution @geoand provided is the intended solution as stated https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#custom-ids

> IDs are often a touchy subject, and not everyone’s up for letting them handled by the framework, once again we have you covered.
>
> You can specify your own ID strategy by extending PanacheEntityBase instead of PanacheEntity. Then you just declare whatever ID you want as a public field: